# What iOS features I can use if I want to load app features based on location?

Tags: ios, iphone, frameworks, location

Is it possible to do lazy loading of Code in iOS? For example, I want to do this location based, when if a user is in India, they get different payment options, but if they are in the US, they see different payment options.

Another example is if we are in Europe we don't want the app to have any code to store the user's data but if we are in the US we want to have that code.  This code should be downloaded to the app without an app update when the user travels from Europe to the US.

Is this even possible on iOS? How would you approach this?

Comment: *"Is it possible to do lazy loading of Code in iOS?"* - Based on my understanding of the App Store rules, no - this might have changed, but originally, this wasn't allowed.  Although that might relate to "dynamically" loading an external code base.  You of course could have all the payment options you support available in your code and simple instantiate the one you want to use at runtime. *"his code should be downloaded to the app without an app update"* - Pretty sure that's against the App Store policies

Comment: Section 4.7 of the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) does provide the provision for executing JavaScript so long as it's done from within the context of WebKit